# CodeFormer-(Background upsampling: False, Face upsampling: False) not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

When I run open source Codeformer python code on Github I get false values.

Example site:

- https://replicate.com/sczhou/codeformer
- https://github.com/sczhou/CodeFormer

I couldn't make detailed improvements like on this site. What is the reason?

[image: Error image]

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask]. error messages must be posted as text. -- **that is not an error.** did you read that text before screencapping and posting it? -- contact the authors of the repository to receive support. visit their issue tracker.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example